# With Asset Pipeline how to serve Images in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I have the following js in my assets/javascript

```
jQuery ->
  if $('.pagination').length
    $(window).scroll ->
      url = $('.pagination .next_page').attr('href')
      if url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 50
        $('.pagination').html('<img src="images/spinner.gif" />')
        $.getScript(url)
    $(window).scroll()
```

Here I am calling for a spinner animation, but is not fetched on localhost.

```
No route matches [GET] "/images/spinner.gif"
```

I have already ran

```
rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=development
```

and my image is properly placed in assets/images (and in public) So this makes me think that the way I call for this image must be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all have a read at [`rails asset pipeline`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) and read difference between [developement](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#in-development) and [production](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#in-production) way of serving assets this will help you understand how the assets are served

If you add an erb extension to a JavaScript asset, making it something such as application.js.erb, then you can use the asset_path helper in your JavaScript code:

```
   jQuery ->
  if $('.pagination').length
    $(window).scroll ->
      url = $('.pagination .next_page').attr('href')
      if url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 50
        $('.pagination').html('<%= asset_path('logo.png') %>')
        $.getScript(url)
    $(window).scroll()
```